# How to write a FileStream to a String

Tags: c#, string, filestream

I like to know, how to read a file using FileStream to a string.

Comment: A `FileStream` is *binary* data - is this actually encoded text? Any reason you're not just using `File.ReadAllText` to start with? Please give more context, including what you've tried already.

Comment: I haven't tried anything till now because I don't really know what to do now...

Comment: Also, its a .txt file.
Plain Text

Comment: You can use File.ReadAllText() or StreamRead.ReadToEnd().

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can grab the codes from here :
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filestream(v=vs.110).aspx

and try if it works for you.

Comment: Yes, thank you a thousand times. FileStream.ToString worked for me.

Comment: Your answer is considered a [link only answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/225370/your-answer-is-in-another-castle-when-is-an-answer-not-an-answer) specially a link to Microsoft that might be invalid in few months. to complete your answer you can copy paste the code here and *also* include a link to original document.